# Symbolic constants vs const variables in C?

Tags: c, memory

Here are two versions of the same program in C. In the first one I use constant integers and in the second, I define my integers as symbolic constants.

1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  const int UPPER = 300;
  const int LOWER = 0;
  const int STEP = 20;


  for (float fahr = UPPER; fahr >= LOWER; fahr = fahr - STEP) {
      printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, ((fahr - 32) * 5/9));
  }

}
```

2. 

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOWER 0 /* lower limit of table.*/
#define UPPER 300 /* upper limit*/
#define STEP 20 /* step size */


int main () {
    for (float fahr = UPPER; fahr >= LOWER; fahr = fahr - STEP) {
        printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, ((fahr - 32) * 5/9));
    }

}
```

To my understanding the only difference between the two is the fact that symbolic constants are replaced with their assigned values by the (pre)compiler.
I'm a bit confused on when should I use one over the other cause I'd rather use const variables at all times.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first snippet defines *objects* (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4); the second uses *values*.

Comment: There are several differences, enough of them and with complications that I would not want to write up an answer without doing research. Often, compiler optimization will produce the same results. But considerations include: Macro replacements with lexical constants will have some type, like `int` for 300. For various numbers `40000`, the type will depend on the C implementation (could be `int` or `long` or something else depending on the implementation’s integer widths). Whereas a `const int` you define will be `int`. This may go unnoticed in many expressions but cause a bug in others.

Comment: Another difference is that some places in C require an *integer constant expression*, such as static array sizes, so the compiler might not accept a `const int` object. Another is you can take the address of `UPPER` defined as `const int` but not of it defined as a macro. Another difference is you can stringize the numeral from a preprocessor macro (as in `printf("%" Stringize(FieldWidth) "s",…);`, where `Stringize` is a macro that applies the `#` operator) but not from a `const int`.

Comment: If the values can be represented by an `int`, an alternative is to use enumerated constants, e.g. `enum { LOWER = 0, UPPER = 300, STEP = 20 };`.

Comment: Another difference is that, with a preprocessor macro, the compiler is guaranteed to always know the value where it is used. With a `const int`, it may be difficult to know the optimizer will make use of the value when the identifier is used.